# How to share a Github repository with a React project and hide your past commits?

Tags: git, github

I'll be sharing a private github repository with someone and I don't want them to see my past commits

Comment: Did you search the web (or SO) for similar topics? There are multiple answers here and elsewhere.

Comment: Git is a version control system. If you don't want to preserve version history, why are you using git in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all past commit history and just end up with a single commit, keeping all the code as is, the fastest way is to just blow your `.git` directory and start it all over.

**WARNING - make sure you have and up-to-date backup before proceeding.** Blowing your `.git` directory as illustrated below will not change your project files, but will erase all local git history in your project, including all branches and commits. This action is irreversible.

After you double-checked the backup, from the root of your project run:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Now you can start a new git repository, make the first commit and push it up to a different remote.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Add code'
git remote add origin <some-other-remote-url>
git push origin master
```